# How does SciPy stats.norm.fit determine the parameters

Tags: scipy, mle

this may not be a suitable question for this forum, but I was just wondering if anyone knows how SciPy's `stats.norm.fit()` method determines distribution parameters? I read somewhere that it uses Maximum Likelihood Estimation, but I cannot find any offical documentation.

Thanks in advance,

BJR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scipy.stats.norm` does indeed calculate the distribution parameters using maximum likelihood estimation. Specifically, it minimizes the log-likelihood.

`norm` is a subclass of `rv_continuous`, which implements the `fit` method. Hence, you'll find [the documentation of `fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) in the docs of `rv_continuous`.

Comment: Ahh, cool. I did not think to look on the rv_continuous section. Thank's MaxPowers.